# Hover background image disappears behind text

Tags: html, css, menu

With previous help from Stackover, I made a hover menu displaying the days of the week. When you hover over a day, an image appears with text on top. I've got as far as making that. However, now my problem is this: when you mouse over the text, the hover image behind it disappears.

I thought maybe it was an issue that could be fixed using z-index but that didn't work.

I've made a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8unWr/2/)

Here is my CSS

```
#nav {
display:inline;
list-style:none;
position:fixed;
width:1290px;
margin:0 auto; 
left:0px; 
right:0px;
float:clear;
top:130px;
z-index:1000;

}

.menu li {
display:inline;
vertical-align:top; 
float:left;

}

.menu li a {
display:block;
height:407px;
width:250px;

}

.img1 {
width:250px;
height:407px;
position:relative;
}

.thursButton {
width:250px;
height:407px;
display:block;
}

#thursButton {
background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/K8umxhswx/thu.png');
}

#thursButton:hover {
background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/6Rxmxht1d/thu-hover.png');
}
.left p {
color:#FFFFFF;
display:none;
font-size:20px;
left:5px;
position:absolute;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000000;
text-transform:uppercase;
top:100px;
width:245px;
 white-space: pre-line;
word-wrap: break-word;


}

.left:hover p {
display:block;

}
```

The HTML

```
<div id="nav"> <div style="display:inline-block;white-space: nowrap">
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <div class="img1 left"> <a href="#" id="thursButton" class="thursButton" border="0"></a>

            <p><u>Thursday, 19th</u>
Text
<br/>Text
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>

            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Thank you Stackoverflow, as ever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change what is activating the hover.

I also have seen at least 7-10 of these questions... We are here to help not do the project for you mate.

To explain why this is happening,

You are targeting `#thursButton` for the hover state which means you have to be hovering over that to make the change. Once you hover over the text you are no longer hovering over `#thursButton`.

What I did was add the hover state on the parent so where ever you are hovering the parent wil inform the child to make the change.

This is what needs changing,

```
#thursButton:hover {
    background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/6Rxmxht1d/thu-hover.png');
}
```

to,

```
.img1:hover #thursButton {
    background-image:url('http://static.tumblr.com/2wdsnoc/6Rxmxht1d/thu-hover.png');
}
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8unWr/3/).

Comment: I know... I'm sorry. I appreciate all your help and I take everything on board. I swear I am not being lazy. I only turn to SO when I am really stuck. I've devoured two CSS books and watched numerous videos

Comment: No need to apologize mate, the best advice I could give you was to try and isolate all the problems into a main problem. CSS can be tricky to learn and I've only started learning all of this 2 years ago now. Best of luck regardless mate and hopefully it is smooth sailing from now on. :]

Comment: You're the best, Josh. I only started learning CSS a few months ago :-/

Comment: can I ask you a question? plsssss. I don't want to post another question and feel your wrath :)

Comment: Too late... I got into trouble and received a downvote :'( :-x I edited an old question. SO hates me

Comment: SO doesn't hate you and a down-vote doesn't mean you are in trouble. If I down-vote I will explain my reasoning and it normally pertains to lack of research or lack of effort. Where is the problem and I'll try to help you!

Comment: Well I wished the rest of SO thought the same way as you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477995/keep-hover-menu-open-on-click see :'(

Comment: I think that post is the first one you helped me on! :D

Comment: Here is a helpful link, http://stackoverflow.com/tour, that will show you how to better benefit from SO. It's not that they don't like you or anything but this is a website for professionals, not like social media websites.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the stacking of your elements. You put the hover on the a, but when you hover the text, you are no longer hovering the a, which has the background.

Josh's answer works perfectly fine, however, you can also solve it with pointer-events.

Change the following CSS:

```
.left p {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   display: none;
   font-size: 20px;
   left: 5px;
   position: absolute;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   top: 100px;
   width: 245px;
   white-space: pre-line;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will cause the p to not have any mouse-events. This makes the hover on the a still work.

Comment: +1 for pointer-events - nice one. Although not supported in IE10 and less.

Comment: Wow... Had no idea about pointer-events. Reading up on them now. Thank you, @Sander Koedood!